# Assertion is not working in protractor-cucumber with Chai library

Tags: protractor

I am running a code for navigating to the dashboard from login page and clicking the logout button.

```
 browser.sleep(3000);
 expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(url);
 element(by.css(".frx-header-username span")).click(); 
 element(by.css(".frx-menu-list-container .frx-menu-list")).click();
```

when i am giving the assertion to check whether url is navigated to dashboard or not using

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(url);
```

it always gives success even we pass wrong or correct url.but when i am using

```
return expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(url);
```

it gives success only when passing correct url. but when i am using this code i am not able to execute the code below the "return expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(url);"

I need to execute the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
browser.sleep(3000);
return expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(url).then(() => {
    element(by.css(".frx-header-username span")).click(); 
    return element(by.css(".frx-menu-list-container .frx-menu-list")).click();
});
```